# How to combine column names and values

Tags: python, pandas

think about a df, like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Fist_Name':  ['John', 'Jack', 'Jimmy'],
                           'Last_Name': ['Black','Smith','Lee'],
                           'City': ['NY','Los Angeles','Boston'],
                           'Country': ['USA','USA','USA']})
```

i want to create a new column that contains columnname and values of all the row before itself.

like first row of the new column output be like:

```
'Fist_Name: John, Last_Name: Black, City: NY, Country: USA'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to concatenate the columns using join.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Fist_Name':  ['John', 'Jack', 'Jimmy'],
                           'Last_Name': ['Black','Smith','Lee'],
                           'City': ['NY','Los Angeles','Boston'],
                           'Country': ['USA','USA','USA']})

print (df)
def address(x):
   return ', '.join([col + ': ' + x[col] for col in df.columns])

df['new'] = df.apply(address, axis = 1)

print (df['new'])
```

The output of this will be:

```
  Fist_Name Last_Name         City Country
0      John     Black           NY     USA
1      Jack     Smith  Los Angeles     USA
2     Jimmy       Lee       Boston     USA

0    Fist_Name: John, Last_Name: Black, City: NY, Country: USA         
1    Fist_Name: Jack, Last_Name: Smith, City: Los Angeles, Country: USA
2    Fist_Name: Jimmy, Last_Name: Lee, City: Boston, Country: USA
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend keep the `dict` type

```
df['new'] = df.to_dict('r')
df
  Fist_Name  ...                                                new
0      John  ...  {'Fist_Name': 'John', 'Last_Name': 'Black', 'C...
1      Jack  ...  {'Fist_Name': 'Jack', 'Last_Name': 'Smith', 'C...
2     Jimmy  ...  {'Fist_Name': 'Jimmy', 'Last_Name': 'Lee', 'Ci...
[3 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: glad i learned this method, but it is especially necessary in the format I specified like columname:value

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to manipulate the output from [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) by converting the entries to `str`:

```
df['new'] = [str(row).replace("'","")[1:-1] for row in df.to_dict('r')]

print(df['new'][0])
#'Fist_Name: John, Last_Name: Black, City: NY, Country: USA'
```

By using `str.replace` you can remove the single quotes (`"'"`), then, with the slice you can remove brackets (`'{'` and `'}'`).